# Javascript close alert box

Tags: javascript, dialog, alert, dom-events

I want to be able to close an alert box automatically using Javascript after a certain amount of time or on a specific event (i.e. `onkeypress`).  From my research, it doesn't look like that's possible with the built-in `alert()` function.  Is there a way to override it and have control over the dialog box that it opens?

Also, I don't want an override that shows a hidden div as the alert.  I need an actual dialog box.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As mentioned previously you really can't do this.  You can do a modal dialog inside the window using a UI framework, or you can have a popup window, with a script that auto-closes after a timeout... each has a negative aspect.   The modal window inside the browser won't create any notification if the window is minimized, and a programmatic (timer based) popup is likely to be blocked by modern browsers, and popup blockers.

Answer (score 11):

Appears you can somewhat accomplish something similar with the [Notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API) API.  You can't control how long it stays visible (probably an OS preference of some kind--unless you specify requireInteraction true, then it stays up forever or until dismissed or until you close it), and it requires the user to click "allow notifications" (unfortunately) first, but here it is:

If you want it to close after 1s (all OS's leave it open 1s at least):

```
var notification = new Notification("Hi there!", {body: "some text"});
setTimeout(function() {notification.close()}, 1000);
```

If you wanted to show it longer than the "default" you could bind to the onclose callback and show another repeat notification I suppose, to replace it.

Ref: inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19651500/32453) answer, though that answer doesn't work in modern Chrome anymore, but the Notification API does.

Comment: The requireinteraction flag is also "supposed" to make it stay up indefinitely (until they close it or you do with the #close method) FWIW (on OS .X default timeout is 5s FWIW)

Answer (score 7):

no control over the dialog box, if you had control over the dialog box you could write obtrusive javascript code. (Its is not a good idea to use alert for anything except debugging)

Comment: Now... I'll admit I still do it from time to time but... really? Alert for debugging? You're *advocating* that?

Comment: `alert()` is perfect for debugging. Last time I used it during writing userjs on my iPad @ office. God bless alert()! :)

Comment: I find both alert and console.log to be helpful in different situations. Never use `alert();` within a loop though. Nice way to crash a computer :)

Comment: "no good for anything except debugging" != advocating lol

Answer (score 4):

> I want to be able to close an alert
>   box automatically using javascript
>   after a certain amount of time or on a
>   specific event (i.e. onkeypress)

A sidenote: if you have an Alert("data"), you won't be able to keep code running in background (AFAIK)... . the dialog box is a modal window, so you can't lose focus too. So you won't have any keypress or timer running...

Comment: My alert box would be fired by an asynchronous event, so this should not be a problem (in theory).

Comment: JavaScript isn't asynchronous. Calling alert/confirm/prompt freezes all script processing (and indeed often the entire web browser) until the user answers.

Comment: @bobince JavaScript does allow *asynchronous* behavior; but it is not *multithreaded*. If the thread freezes in a block of code --- asynchronous or not --- all code will be frozen at that point.

Answer (score 3):

Try boot box plugin.

```
var alert = bootbox.alert('Massage')
alert.show();
setTimeout(function(){alert.modal('hide'); }, 4000);
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could open a popup window and call *that* a dialog box. I'm unsure of the details, but I'm pretty sure you can close a window programmatically that you opened from javascript. Would this suffice?

Comment: Nice work around, but OP wanted alert dialog only. But this should do for those who want control over dialogs. +1

Answer (score 2):

The only real alternative here is to use some sort of custom widget with a modal option. Have a look at jQuery UI for an example of a dialog with these features. Similar things exist in just about every JS framework you can mention.

Comment: I know, but unfortunately, it's really the only way to handle this stuff in JavaScript.

Comment: No need to get annoyed, you asked a question and I said it couldn't be done, which it can't, and offered an alternative.

Comment: Wow... years later, I can't believe how much of an idiot I was.  Sorry I was such an ass when all you were trying to do was help.

Answer (score 0):

If you do it programmatically in JS it will be like reinventing the wheel. I recommend using a [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) plugin called [jGrowl](http://cool-javascripts.com/effects/jgrowl-to-show-unobtrusive-messages.html)

Comment: jGrowl simply displays an inline div.  I need a dialog box.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

#### Maybe Use The HTML Dialog Tag

I arrived at this question / answers while looking for the same, and I found an alternative on W3Schools using the dialog. I modified their example a fair amount to automate the opening and closing. The dialog tag usage is shown in the HTML / JavaScript below. Herein, I use `setTimeout`s for the opening and closing. I plan to replace the `setTimeout`s with JavaScript functions that open the dialog before a fetch is called, and closing the dialog will happen when a promise, that takes longer to fulfill, IS fulfilled.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>The HTML Dialog Object</h1>
        <dialog id="myDialog">This is a dialog window</dialog>
    <h2>The Dialog will open 3 seconds after window load and close, 5 seconds after first showing, on it's own</h2>

    <script>
      function showDialog(dialog) {
        dialog.show();
        closeDialog(dialog);
      }

      function closeDialog(dialog) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          dialog.close();
        }, 5000);
      }

      function init() {
        setTimeout(function () {
          const dialog = document.getElementById("myDialog");
          showDialog(dialog);
        }, 3000);
      }

      init();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Wish I could show a video of this, but this code will run in your VS Code Live Server just as it is.

Answer (score -2):

You actually can do this you can basically listen for this pop up to happen and then confirm true before it ever "pops up",

```
if(window.alert){
  return true
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use label and set its fade in and out time for e.g 
Hide it initially and show on click.
$('#div_Message').fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(1500);

Answer (score -5):

```
window.setTimeout('alert("Message goes here");window.close();', 5000);
```