# Can i close confirm box in javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to close confirm box after some timeout. So can i do that? If we can;t do this then I like to use jquery dialogue. Can we make that dialogue as similar to confirm box?

Comment: Yes, you can style the jquery dialog similar to the confirm box. No, you can't close the confirm automatically.

Comment: Very similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463368/javascript-close-alert-box

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't, the user is the only one allowed to interact with the built in confirmation.  Doing one with jQuery isn't too bad though:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation