# Need to click `confirm()` in a webBrowser control from C#

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, confirm

I'm using a `WebBrowser` control in a C# Window Forms application, and trying to confirm a `confirm()` box that was opened in the `webBrowser` by JavaScript.

The JavaScript code:

```
confirm("confirmMe");
```

How can I click `OK` on the dialog that opened?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean "confirm"?

Comment: If you want to close it from the server side, there's no way. If you want to do it from the client side, take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297804/can-i-close-confirm-box-in-javascript-code) question.

Comment: @empereurAiman - yes, im sry.

Comment: This is a Windows Forms or WPF application, with a WebBrowser control?

Comment: @andersonPimentel - there is alot of things that people said that there is no way to do them, like call a javascript function in c# - there is a way that i found by myself, but i mean like - there is anyway i will be able to change the javasscript code over there? i mean cancel the confirm message by doing something? make a new function on-page?

Comment: @mason - Windows Forms

Comment: Can you explain why are you trying to close a `confirm` window on a web browser from a Windows Forms application?

Comment: You can use the same technique to automate `confirm`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18691219/1768303

Answer (score 0):

If you have no control over the web application, there's no way to close the `confirm` window, as it pauses the script execution waiting for the user input.

If you have control over the web application, try using something like [JQueryUI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation), which has a `close` method.

Comment: Having control over the WebApplication doesn't nessicarily mean that you can modify the web page your navigating to

Comment: It's actually quite possible, provided the OP has control over the browser: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18691219/1768303.

Comment: @Noseratio True. That's way beyond my knowledge in WinForms. Thanks for the info. I think you should post as an answer.

Comment: @johnny5 Know that, but I'm afraid he wants a complex solution for something that could be a lot simpler.

Comment: if the alert box pops up in the same position percent wise you could probably trigger a click from c#

Comment: Im gald you people trying to help me but still I cant find the soulotion, thats not my site so I cant do anything to the code.