# alert should close after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript

I have simple javascript alert box i want it to close automatically after 5 second.
if possible help please.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_alert()
{
alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
}
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="show_alert()" value="Show alert box" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463368/javascript-close-alert-box discussed this at length.

Comment: You seem to be confusing Java and JavaScript — they are very different programming languages.

Comment: you cannot do this, you can use a temporized div to show customized messages to user.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot close a JavaScript alert box, the user has to.  If you want to do something like this, I suggest using a custom modal popup (like jQuery UI).

Comment: actually i have a feedback form on site and i want after form submission user should get java alert box of successful submission. and it should close automatically. well do u think jquery modal popup will be fine for this. i just want your opinion.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to close classic alert box.  You can male your own using HTML + lock events, and use timer for closing.