# Close dialog after 5 seconds with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm implementing an add wishlist function to my rails app. So far I can dialog the message and get it to fade after 5 seconds. The issue is, once faded out and the user clicks on another "add wishlist" no dialog. They have to refresh the page. Im still learning so I know what's going on. I need to close the dialog with js but how?

[Coming from my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38545952/how-to-apply-style-to-the-correct-tag-with-jquery/):

**HTML**

```
<section data-id="notification"></section>
```

**JavaScript**

```
...

// Calling the notification();
// You need to reduce that data string!
notification("<div id='noti' class='alert alert-success'><a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a><p>WishList Added!</p></div>");

...

function notification(data){
    $( "[data-id=notification]" ).append( data ).delay(5000).fadeOut(400); // I've tried adding .dialog('close')
    $('#noti').dialog('close'); // this gives an error.
  }

...
```

To conclude, when user adds to wishlist, an dialog will show. User can manually close the dialog or it will close itself after `x` seconds. If dialog closes it self and user clicks another add wishlist, alert re-appears etc. Some how I need to remove it from the dom.

Maybe it wont make sense to display a message every time the user adds/removes a wishlist but this will be useful for other parts of my app.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152729/alert-should-close-after-5-seconds) is 4 years ago. Has anything changed since? I need both: user close and js close.

Comment: seems like you have a problem with turbotlinks, are you using turbolinks 5?

Comment: @Marv-C No. It's not installed.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Yes I am. I was thinking of simulating a `.click()`. Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `alert('close')` :

```
$( "[data-id=notification]" ).append( data ).delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
$('#noti').alert('close');
```

Or using `setTimeout` :

```
$( "[data-id=notification]" ).append( data );
setTimeout(function() { $('#noti').alert('close'); }, 5000);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi. That works if I remove `.delay(5000).fadeOut(400);` as it leaves a `display:none` class. Any way around this? Would be neat to have a fade out. If not, no problem.

Comment: You're welcome, please try to add a fiddle so i can check the fade out.

Comment: Add the `seTimeout()` to your jsfiddle and you'll see.

Comment: You have to choose one of them not the both in same time.. use `setTimeout` or `delay` recheck my answer please... fiddle using `setTimeout`http://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/qYqjS/47/

Comment: Your first code will fade, then clicks but when I check the inspector I see a class of display none and when I click another add wishlist, no alert. If it's too much, I'll use the last code.

Comment: well just use the `setTimeout` :)