# C# WebBrowser alert close:

Tags: c#

Is there anyone here knows how to handle the alert message from [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) (Alert).

Here is the scenario, i login to a specific website, then when login thing is done, there is an alert message generated by Javascript. My problem is that i can't close the Alert Message through codes. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463368/javascript-close-alert-box

Comment: I've updated your question to make it clear that you're using the WebBrowser class specifically.

Comment: Did you try `SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")` ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta, i've tried that man. the problem is that the main app stock up (whole thing freeze) with that alertMessage. I've tried to create a new Thread that will allow me to SendKeys, but still not working.

Comment: @Apes Jaguar any update on your problem? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The alert box in JavaScript is completely client-driven and you won't be able to access it from the server-side. Unfortunately there's no real way to "force close" an alert or confirm dialog box, even utilizing JavaScript. Is there any specific reason you need to close this alert box and, better yet, can't you modify the login code in C# to NOT generate the alert box?

Comment: I believe he is using the WebBrowser class in C#. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx

Comment: I am creating a bot for Web, like auto-login, auto-download files, etc. Problems are those annoying pop-up messages. when pop-up appears, the whole process freeze or waiting for end user input.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to read up the document body and via DOM manipulation remove that javascript block (or any block that contains it).

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is best fit as a comment