# Is it possible to close confirm box after a time interval?

Tags: javascript

I need to display this message to the user where the user can click 'Yes' or 'No'. If the user doesn't respond in 2 minutes, the window needs to closed. Opening a new page is one way. My question is, is it possible to do this with a confirm box? Can a confirm box be automatically closed after 2 minutes?

Comment: check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463368/javascript-close-alert-box

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot do that with the native `confirm()` as it blocks JavaScript execution on that page until the user has "answered" but there are lots of HTML/JavaScript-based inplementations out there where you could easily add such behaviour.
And they often look better, too. :)

Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/972832/298479 for an example. To create the timeout, you'd simply `window.setTimeout(function() { $('#dialog').dialog('close'); }, 120000);` when opening the dialog.

Comment: For clarification, native dialog boxes suspend run time on the line the dialog was invoked.

Answer (score 4):

`Alert` and `Confirm` boxes cannot be scripted to close. Use a modal dialog instead. This usually consists of an absolutely-positioned DIV and a translucent overlay that covers the whole page.

Comment: And with jQuery UI it's extremely easy to do.