# Close a JavaScript Confirm pop up without clicking OK or Cancel buttons

Tags: javascript, dom-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Javascript close alert box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463368/javascript-close-alert-box)

A confirm box can be opened by,
`confirm("Sure?");`
which opens a confirm pop up with two buttons- OK and Cancel.
The pop up closes when either of the two buttons are clicked. How can we close the pop up without clicking the buttons, pragmatically? Can we trigger the event which closes the pop up using JavaScript?

Comment: You can't because JS execution is blocked as long as the dialog is open. You have to use your own dialog implementation.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463368/javascript-close-alert-box ... this affects alert boxes too as an FYI.

Comment: Also kind of duplicatish: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416798/is-it-possible-to-close-confirm-box-after-a-time-interval

Comment: Yes, you are right. The link you provided with the question is very similar to what I had asked.

Comment: I presume that hitting escape is not an option either?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer:  The three `DOM0` windows of `alert`, `confirm` and `prompt` are modal windows.  The browser (or the browser window, depending) freezes when those using one of those input methods and *nothing* Javascript-wise happens.

The only thing you can do is to create a popup `DIV` with your own confirm buttons and give your popup window callback methods on what to do on `confirm` `accept` and `cancel.`

A `setTimeout` could be used to auto-close the window after a pause.

Answer (score 2):

No, because that function is blocking the browser. No JavaScript code will run during the time while it is open - not even scheduled timeouts and other event handlers.

See [window.confirm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.confirm) on developer.mozilla.org.

For an example of something that acts in a way that you want, see [this example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation) of the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) library.

Answer (score 0):

You can only achieve this by creating your own Confirmation box using Modal popup and setting the   setTimeout() or setInterval() against it.
or try this if it helps....http://cool-javascripts.com/effects/jgrowl-to-show-unobtrusive-messages.html