# Close onbeforeonload alert after a period of time

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

I´m showing the default alert when the user is navigating away from my web application. The problem is that if the user doesn´t respond to the default modal, after 2 minutes, the session of my application dies, so I would like to know if I´m able to close this pop up after a period of time, or, if that´s not possible, use a custom modal so I can handle it.
I know there are A LOT of similar questions to this one, but I couldn´t find a solution, so I thought creating a new question could help me.

Thannk you in advance.

UPDATE: after a lot of research, I´ve come to the conclusion that it´s not possible to close the browser default pop up, or overwrite the alert on this event, so I had to come to another solution that nothing has to do with the solution I was looking for.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10416824/484780

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to close confirm box after a time interval?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416798/is-it-possible-to-close-confirm-box-after-a-time-interval)

Answer (score 0):

after a lot of research, I´ve come to the conclusion that it´s not possible to close the browser default pop up, or overwrite the alert on this event, so I had to come to another solution that nothing has to do with the solution I was looking for.