# Redirect to another page after alert()?

Tags: jquery, alert

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript close alert box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463368/javascript-close-alert-box)

Hi I would like to ask if it's possible to have an id `#myID` which when clicked will pop-up an alert box and after a few seconds **WITHOUT** clicking the `OK` button on alert it will redirect to another page? Here's my code:

```
 $('#myID).click(function(){
     alert('Ta-da! Do not click the OK button just wait for a few seconds before it redirects to other page.');  
 })
```

Somehow that's what I want. Is that possible?

Comment: Only with a custom dialog, not with the built-in `alert`.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks, but how would I do that on the custom dialog?

Comment: @CHi: HTML + CSS + JS `<div id="my-dialog">Custom Message</div>` AND `#my-dialog { /*CSS Properties to center and zindex*/}` AND JS to add  dialog to DOM, add timeout, and maybe put a nice overlay on things.

Comment: Or.. heres an idea.. in most browsers an alert in a sense halts the script til an action is made. But even then, with this logic Im thinkin.. you could always just setTimeout and give it a few seconds.. but thats only if you want to use the default alert, there is also "yes" "no" alert dialogs and other things to consider.

Comment: @chris that doesn't work. alert stops execution of a script. the timer essentially stops until the script is resumed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a custom dialog: A quick one if you dont already ahave any plugins like jQuery ui in your site.

```
var dialog = $('<div id="dialog"> You are going away, Bye Bye </div>');
dialog.css({
    position:'fixed',
    top: 100,
    left: '50%',
    width: '200px',
    'margin-left': '-100px',
    'z-index' : 99999,
    border: '1px solid #444444',
    'background-color' : '#FFFFF'
    });
$('body').append(dialog);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R7qSR/

Comment: I added the timeout that OP wanted at the end. http://jsfiddle.net/R7qSR/1/ `var t=setTimeout(function(){$("#dialog").remove();},3000)`