# How can I auto hide alert box after it showing it?

Tags: javascript

All I want to do is, how can I auto hide alert box within specific seconds after showing it?

All I know is,

```
setTimeout(function() { 
      alert('close'); 
}, 5000);

// This will appear alert after 5 seconds
```

No need for this I want to disappear alert after showing it within seconds.

**Needed scenario :**

1. Show alert
2. Hide/terminate alert within 2 seconds

Answer (score 35, accepted):

tldr; **[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Tq5m3/)**

This functionality is not possible with an alert. However, you could use a div

```
function tempAlert(msg,duration)
{
 var el = document.createElement("div");
 el.setAttribute("style","position:absolute;top:40%;left:20%;background-color:white;");
 el.innerHTML = msg;
 setTimeout(function(){
  el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
 },duration);
 document.body.appendChild(el);
}
```

Use this like this:

```
tempAlert("close",5000);
```

Comment: thanks Travis, I need alert not custom alert

Comment: so far it's too close to the solution, i will try it.

Comment: hi    am getting null on the parentNode...On the line el.parentNode.removeChild(el);.. how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't close an alert box with Javascript.

You could, however, use a window instead:

```
var w = window.open('','','width=100,height=100')
w.document.write('Message')
w.focus()
setTimeout(function() {w.close();}, 5000)
```

Comment: Most popup blockers will prevent the new window from showing...

Comment: Thank you very much for your support mr.DoorKnob , but i need alert itself not a custom alert
example:
1- show alert 
2- hide alert after 2 seconds

Comment: @MaherNajiEl-Ghali Then you can't. There is no way to close an alert with JS.

Answer (score 2):

impossible with javascript. 
Just as another alternative to suggestions from other answers: consider using jGrowl: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jGrowl

Comment: hmmm.. interesting , is this as mac growl ?? , i will use this resource in futur , thanks Mr.Alex

Comment: yes, it's a jQuery plugin which shows messages looking like growl-messages. It is stylable and flexible. The "disappear after n seconds" behaviour, as well as permanent messages are built-in. Give it a try )

Answer (score 1):

You can also try Notification API. Here's an example:

```
function message(msg){
    if (window.webkitNotifications) {
        if (window.webkitNotifications.checkPermission() == 0) {
        notification = window.webkitNotifications.createNotification(
          'picture.png', 'Title', msg);
                    notification.onshow = function() { // when message shows up
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            notification.close();
                        }, 1000); // close message after one second...
                    };
        notification.show();
      } else {
        window.webkitNotifications.requestPermission(); // ask for permissions
      }
    }
    else {
        alert(msg);// fallback for people who does not have notification API; show alert box instead
    }
    }
```

To use this, simply write:

```
message("hello");
```

Instead of:

```
alert("hello");
```

---

**Note:** Keep in mind that it's only currently supported in Chrome, Safari, Firefox and some mobile web browsers (jan. 2014)

Find supported browsers [**here.**](http://caniuse.com/notifications)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in "today's Chrome" however it may have been replaced by the new Notification API which somewhat fits the bill, great idea, inspired this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45152906/32453