# How to "auto close" Alert boxes

Tags: javascript, alert, legacy-code

We have a control that was made by a company that no longer exists.
For some odd reason on page load it has now started rendering something like this to the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 alert('Your license has expired!')
</script>
```

Since the company no longer exists we can't get support and the control is also very complex and is running in some legacy code that can't be quickly replaced so simply rewriting the page is also not an option (yet).

What I need to do for the time being is to have the dialog either be removed from the page before it renders or auto closed by some script ...

Any ideas?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463368/javascript-close-alert-box

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15466802/how-can-i-auto-hide-alert-box-after-it-showing-it

Comment: @Atrox111, that does not help with the OP's problem

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can not close an alert box, just you can hijack window.alert

```
window._alert = window.alert;
window.alert = function () {    
};
```

The code would have to appear before the third party library's code. What this means is, if you want to use an alert, you would have to change your code.

One way would to call the method that has the reference

```
window._alert("hi");
```

Other way would be to overload the "new" function

```
window._alert = window.alert;
window.alert = function (msg, showItNow) {    
    if (showItNow) {
        window._alert(msg);
    }
};
window.alert("BOOOO!");  //I will not show up
window.alert("hi", true); //I will show up
```

Comment: If the 3:rd party code triggers the alert immediately, you can restore  the alert function after the 3:rd party code has been executed: `window.alert = window._alert;`. Of course, this doesn't work if the alert is triggered asynchronously.

Comment: A variation to epascarello's solution is to instead of sending in a boolean to decide if a real alert window should appear instead simply check if msg is "Your license has expired!" and in that case ignore calling window._alert().

Comment: @Strille, Man I have not had my coffee this morning, that is a good idea! lol

Comment: When a hack is needed ... stack overflow is home :)

Answer (score -1):

I think you cannot do that because and alert box needs a confirmation.you can rather make a popup alert and set it to close with timeout.

Comment: I can see you did not read the OP's post. The OP has **NO** control over the alert.