# Autoclose alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert, auto-close

Is there any way to close a javascript `alert()` automatically?

I have an alert

```
alert("Error found");
```

I want to close it after a few second. Is that possible or shall I go for jQuery dialogue

Comment: I don't think that's possible; never seen it in 6 years of coding.

Comment: `@sreeekesh ` You can not close an alert box, just you can hide it .

Comment: @ankit337: Hide it how?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15466802/how-can-i-auto-hide-alert-box-after-it-showing-it

Comment: Thanx guys. I think I will go with jQuery dialogue then :)

Comment: `@Nikolay` Yes i have use that . In my Code same way .

Comment: `@joe` here is link `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321574/how-to-auto-close-alert-boxes`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Tq5m3/43/)**

This functionality is not possible with an alert. However, you could use a div

```
function tempAlert(msg,duration)
{
 var el = document.createElement("div");
 el.setAttribute("style","position:absolute;top:40%;left:20%;background-color:white;");
 el.innerHTML = msg;
 setTimeout(function(){
  el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
 },duration);
 document.body.appendChild(el);
}
```

Use this like this:

```
tempAlert("close",1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't close alert any how .

But you can use div To show your alert MSG.

```
  function Mymsg(msg,duration)
{
 var alt = document.createElement("div");
     alt.setAttribute("style","position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;background-color:white;");
     alt.innerHTML = msg;
     setTimeout(function(){
      alt.parentNode.removeChild(alt);
     },duration);
     document.body.appendChild(alt);
}
```

You can use as :

```
Mymsg('close',2000)
```

Answer (score 3):

**[jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/woold/gztvh0e4/30/)**

Basically you can imitate an alert box with a popup window and close it whenever you want, call the following function:

```
function myAlert(msg,title,width,height,timeout) {
    var myWindow = window.open("", "",`width=${width},height=${height},left=${(window.outerWidth/2-width/2)},top=0`); //open a new popup at the top height and middle width of the current window
    myWindow.document.write(`<center id="msg">`+msg+`</center>`); //write the message you want to display
    myWindow.document.title = title; //write the title of the alert box
    setTimeout(function(){
        myWindow.close(); //close the popup
    },timeout||3000) //in 3 secondes (3000 milliseconds)
}
```

by the way if you want to close the alert on call, just use define the variable "myWindow" earlier (out of myAlert() function) as a global variable and then call `myWindow.close();` once you already called myAlert() and remove

```
setTimeout(function(){
    myWindow.close(); //close the popup
},timeout||3000) //in 3 secondes (3000 milliseconds)
```

from the function myAlert()

Answer (score 2):

I updated the style settings, so it shows like a splash screen in the center of your page, and centers the text inside it.

Call it like this:

```
alertTimeout("System Message<br>This is a test message<br>This alert will auto-close",5000)
```

The function:

```
function alertTimeout(mymsg,mymsecs)
{
 var myelement = document.createElement("div");
myelement.setAttribute("style","background-color: grey;color:black; width: 450px;height: 200px;position: absolute;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;margin:auto;border: 4px solid black;font-family:arial;font-size:25px;font-weight:bold;display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; text-align: center;");
 myelement.innerHTML = mymsg;
 setTimeout(function(){
  myelement.parentNode.removeChild(myelement);
 },mymsecs);
 document.body.appendChild(myelement);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**This is another solution**

window.setTimeout('alert("Error Found ");window.close();', 5000);

Comment: it's not closing alert, but whole page