# Closing an alert box does not work on VDI via test agent

Tags: coded-ui-tests, mtm

When we run a CodedUI test case with the following code to close a dialog popup (JavaScript alert):

```
CurrentBrowser.PerformDialogAction(BrowserDialogAction.Ok);
```

Or, with the following code:

```
var popupWindow = new WinWindow(null);
popupWindow.SearchProperties.Add("Name", "Message from webpage", "ClassName", "#32770");
popupWindow.TechnologyName = "MSAA";

var okButton = new WinButton(popupWindow) { TechnologyName = "MSAA" };
okButton.SearchProperties.Add("Name", "OK");

okButton.SetFocus();
Keyboard.SendKeys(okButton, "{ENTER}");
```

It works locally, but when we run the via Microsoft Test Manager on a VDI with the same version of Windows and Internet Explorer the popup is not closed. No error is thrown, the VDI just waits.

We are using the following versions:

> TFS 2012 update 4 test agent
>   Internet Explorer 10
>   Windows 7 Enterprise

Does anyone know why this could be and how it can be solved?

Comment: Can you try it without the ("Name", "Message from webpage") ? It might be a culture setting thing (other language or some added text for your service account) that it can't find the popupWindow.

Comment: Thanks Rolf. Unfortunately this does not make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that locally I used Visual Studio 2015 to run. The build and MTM used TFS 2012. There was a mismatch in CodedUI dlls. Apparently something was fixed in CodedUi that made clicking on an alert box possible.

Removing conditional choosing of (old) dll's:

```
<Choose>
<When Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '10.0' And '$(IsCodedUITest)' == 'True'">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
</When>
```

from the csproj file and referencing newer versions solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you want to use SetFocus on the window not the button. What is DrawHighlight doing? Have you removed ClassName search property from Window?

Comment: Hi Alex, I did not remove the ClassName search property. I will try to remove that. Another suggestion (by Rolf) was to execute JavaScript from C# to close the alert box. I will try that if removing the class name does not help. `DrawHighlight` was there to check if the box was highlighted. I'll post the results here.

Comment: Update 1: [seems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020830/autoclose-alert) you cannot close an alert with JavaScript. This makes the JavaScript solution not going to work. I will follow your hints.

Comment: We did remove all the information. Resulting code was: `var popupWindow = new WinWindow(null) { TechnologyName = "MSAA" };

            var okButton = new WinButton(popupWindow) { TechnologyName = "MSAA" };
            okButton.SearchProperties.Add("Name", "OK");
            Keyboard.SendKeys(okButton, "{ENTER}");`. That did not work. I try to remove the "Name" property! If that does not work: another thing that might be the cause is the version of CodedUI. We are using TFS 2012 on the VDI and locally we run with 2013/2015 CodedUI dlls.

Comment: `code` var popupwindow = new WinWindow();  popupwindow.SearchProperties.Add("Name", "Message from webpage"); var okButton = new WinButton(popupwindow);                                      okButton.SearchProperties.Add("Name", "OK");                                      Mouse.Click(okButton);