# How to hide alert box in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to hide the alert box.
Alert box at last line pops up first, after that when ajax call completes other alert box in if condition pops up, which pops up below the first one.

I want to hide the first alert box when second one pops up.

```
     var xmlhttp;    
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else {// code for IE6, IE5
         xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
         if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
            if(xmlhttp.status==200) {               
               alert(getLocalizedString("partialExportFCdata_ui.msg3");
            }else{
               alert(getLocalizedString("partialExportFCdata_ui.msg4");
            }
         }
         var obj = document.getElementById("ChkBoxHeader");
         checkAll(false, obj.name);
      }
      xmlhttp.open("POST","FCTagService?    htmlaction=updateTags&records="+sb.toString()+"&containsid="+containsid+"&catalogIdStr="+catalogIdStr, true);
      xmlhttp.send();
      alert(getLocalizedString("partialExportFCdata_ui.msg7"); //Last alert box
```

Comment: You can't, you don't have control over closing of alert box.

Instead you can use light box, which you can show and hide as you wish.

Comment: this will help you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321574/how-to-auto-close-alert-boxes

Comment: @user3036097 there are lots of post similar to your question..request you to search before creating new..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot. This is browser specific and so you cannot control it. You can simply force it to show.

Comment: No problems, sorry things aren't working out with alert :) Consider using popups of any framework..

Answer (score 1):

Browser's build in Popup messages are not good to use in such context, you should make use of some jquery component for doing this.
Alert dialog box should mainly used for debugging purpose.