# javascript alert box close automatically

Tags: javascript

I need a function, which close the alert box (window) in few seconds automatically:

```
$("#upload-btn").on('click', function() {
  var dt = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
  if (window.Lollipop) {
     window.Lollipop.save(dt);
  }
   $.post('saveImage.php',
       {
           img : dt
       }, function(data) {
           if(data){
               alert("Image Saved"); 
           }
       });
```

Comment: Not possible. The only option would be a dialog box ( aka modal )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I auto hide alert box after it showing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15466802/how-can-i-auto-hide-alert-box-after-it-showing-it)

Comment: You can try toast notification instead of alert message box. From description of your question toast notification suits your requirement.

Answer (score 3):

There is no web api function to close the opened `alert`.

Answer (score 0):

It's NOT possible via standard Web API to close the standard alert box, but you can define your own function or override the `alert()` function (which is the bad way, better to define own).

```
const temporaryAlert = function( text, duration ) {
    console.assert(typeof text === "string");
    console.assert(text.length > 0);
    console.assert(typeof duration === "number");

    const item = document.createElement("div");
    item.innerText = text;
    // item.style - add some CSS-stuff to customize the box style
    window.setTimeout(() => item.parentNode.removeChild(item), duration);
    return document.body.appendChild(item);
};
```