# How can i close popup alert automatically by using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

when user clicks on a button i want to show a popup alert with some message like "you are redirecting" and after 2 to 3 seconds popup alert needs to close automatically. 
Is it possible to do this one in javascript ?
could any one suggest how to achieve this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15466802/how-can-i-auto-hide-alert-box-after-it-showing-it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript close alert box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463368/javascript-close-alert-box)

Answer (score -1):

you can use `setTimeout` function to achieve this.

```
document.getElementById('my-btn').onClick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  showPopup();
  setTimeout(function () {
    location.href = 'new location';
  }, 2000);
}
```