# How to click on "OK" button inside alert pop-up window?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS, so please be patient.

I have this alert pop-up window and I would like to write a piece of code that clicks the OK button inside it whenever it comes up. How can I do it?

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Alert</h2>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
alert("I am an alert box!");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I doubt you can.  An `alert()` is specifically to alert the user, and it's a blocking operation until the user dismisses the dialog.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish and why?

Comment: This is not possible, because the alert box is a widget from browser manufactors. And this support only customised text. You have to create a modal popup for you own.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15466802/how-can-i-auto-hide-alert-box-after-it-showing-it   you try this article to create your own alert box that can be controlled by js

Comment: Well, my question stems from a completely different problem regarding an RPA project. Basically this pop-up comes up in some cases and we would like to run a piece of JS code that can click OK on it. Remember I'm talking about a robot that faces this kind of window (and for some reasons cannot identify it sometimes).