# How to add setTimeout within Axios Scope

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Display notification in `catch` block of Axios.

**problem encountered is**
Error Message not hiding after specified time using setTimeout.

Comment: What is `NotificationMeta`?

Comment: @NickParsons Yes I have updated my code for ```NotificationMeta```

Comment: So `NotificationMeta` is just an object in your code? Changing it won't cause `Notification` to update/rerender (objects aren't special in React, changing a property in an object won't do anything if that object's value isn't being read again, which will only occur when a rerender occurs). It needs to be state if you want that to occur.

Comment: Okay I understood what you meant. I am trying to add state to ```Notifications``` passing meta to ```useState(NotificationMeta.display)```.

Comment: @NickParsons I did updated the state in ```Notifications```. However I still fail to hide the notification after 3 secs.

Comment: The thing that will cause a rerender is calling your `setDisplay` function. While you have a use-effect setup to trigger when `NotificationMeta.display` changes, that use-effect will only check if  `NotificationMeta.display` has changed when `Notification` has rerendered, so if it's never rerendering,  `NotificationMeta.display` will never be checked for changes. Remove the `useEffect`, and instead pass `setDisplay` as a prop down to `Component B` to that you can call `setDisplay()`.

Comment: @NickParsons Great. It worked. I just created the useState signature and exported ```setNotification``` as a meta param. . It worked like charm. Thank you.

Comment: While that may work, you shouldn't be passing things to other components like that, you'll especially find issues if you have multiple `Notification` components. You should be passing it as a prop down to Component B or using `useContext()` to set the value. If `Notification` doesn't have visibility of Comonent B, then you should lift the `display` state up to a something that has visibility of both Component B and `Notificaiton`. See [Sharing state between componentst](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/sharing-state-between-components)

Comment: @NickParsons Notification is in different project. Its a library project. . So I need to npm install the library and import the Meta in Component A and B. Therefore the above approach.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions. Because alert cannot work like this you coded.

1. Using [React toastify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toastify)
2. Making your custom alert

References:

1. Making own toaster like this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_snackbar.asp
2. Making alert like this: [How can I auto hide alert box after it showing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15466802/how-can-i-auto-hide-alert-box-after-it-showing-it)

Comment: Toastify was my first suggestion but lastly we need to bow down and listen to someone who does not even know the ```C``` of ```Coding```.