# Disappear the alert box with time based

Tags: javascript, alert

I want to disappear the alert box after a certain amount of time. I have heard that this is impossible in Javascript, so is there another way of making this happen?

Comment: You need to design a custom alert box, read the answer.... It works

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript close alert box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463368/javascript-close-alert-box)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this jsbin code - A custom alert box for you

**http://jsbin.com/ibUrIxu/1/edit**

or Try this on your **`.html`** file

## Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<script>
function customAlert(msg,duration)
{
 var styler = document.createElement("div");
  styler.setAttribute("style","border: solid 5px Red;width:auto;height:auto;top:50%;left:40%;background-color:#444;color:Silver");
 styler.innerHTML = "<h1>"+msg+"</h1>";
 setTimeout(function()
 {
   styler.parentNode.removeChild(styler);
 },duration);
 document.body.appendChild(styler);
}
  function caller()
  {
    customAlert("This custom alert box will be closed in 2 seconds","2000");
  }
  </script>
  </head>
<body onload="caller()">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Handy!  I tweaked the style to my own preferences ([codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/XLmWZB)) but I'm sure it will get lots of use. :)

Answer (score 1):

> [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U7wqE/4/) -- Here is a custom alert box and function what you need

```
function cancelDiv() {
        $("#div1").hide();
    }

    function ShowDiv() {
        $("#div1").css("backgroundColor", "white");
        $("#div1").show();
        setTimeout(function(){$("#div1").hide()}, 3000)
    }

    $(function () { 
        $("#div1").hide();
        $("#div1").draggable();            
    });
```

Comment: might be a good idea to change `function ShowDiv()` to `function showDiv()`, a capital first letter in a function name is usually reserved for identifying object creation. not that it matters, just a good format and code cleanup idea

Comment: you can't say it jugad @ deepak, this is hack or workaround in programming terms.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a custom alert message. One example of a notification framework is ToastR. You can also create your own message framework.
You cannot dismiss a regular JavaScript alert box though.