# Can I accept an alert with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

i mean on:

```
alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
```

can i accept it with code?

cuz i cant actually even write code on the console when an alerts pops, so I even tried stuff like:

```
function sleep(ms) 
{
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

// this line above is to wait for X time until the code executes
async function whatEver()
{
  await sleep(5000);
  alert.accept();
}

async function whatEver2()
{
  await sleep(5000);
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()).accept();
}
}
```

And none will work, is it even possible to accept the alerts with code? if so, appreciate any help orienting me :)

Comment: Wait, what is that code? You're using WebDriver, so are you automating interactions on a page via Selenium or something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript close alert box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463368/javascript-close-alert-box)

Comment: The real answer is:  no-one uses `alert()` for anything other than a quick debug (and then console.log is better).   If you're using `alert()` in production code (to be used by "*users*"...) then give your developers a slap from me and fail the test.